# Order of bond rotation about alkene

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

How to decide which among these has the greatest bond rotation possible? 1 has the greatest and 2 the least, according to me, I think it is due to the presence of bulky groups. What more factors can effect bond rotation?

Comment: How should I ask these question I really dont have the concept? @Mithoron

Comment: Well, this thought about bulky groups is already something, but what about them really? I think you should use my hint to try different approach, as there's no bulky group in any of these compounds...

Comment: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange

Answer (score 2):

First, recall that a single bond has the highest free rotation possible (and hence it shows conformational isomerism). A double bond instead does not show any rotation at all (hence, $\ce{abC=Cfg}$ type molecules show geometrical isomerism).

So, it's obvious that, the **more double bond character a bond will have, the less likely it is to rotate freely.** Here, we're talking about double bond *character*, because, due to resonance effects, the resonance hybrid in these compounds will only have a partial double bond character.

Thus, you only need to compare the partial double bond character in each compound, and apply the above rule. Bulkiness of the groups isn't really a factor, because the groups actually aren't that bulky, and it isn't a *t*-butyl group anyway.

Comment: Does ether oxygen also have, even if tiny, a resonance share? I know there is even 4-bonded oxygen in some cases but, I don't understand this for ether.

Comment: @GürayHatipoğlu In case 2? Why not! The lone pair on oxygen is in conjugation with the pi bond, and can freely resonate with it :-)